# ionic 3 HttpClient error in connecting api, Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'

Tags: html, angular, ionic3

---

I am using Ionic 3, I am trying to connect to a api and my code is given below.

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'

@Injectable()
export class WeatherProvider {
  apikey = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
  url;
  constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
    console.log('Hello WeatherProvider Provider');
    this.url= 'http://api.wunderground.com/api/'+this.apikey+'/conditions/q';
  }
  getWeather(city, state){
    return this.http.get(this.url+'/'+state+'/'+city+'.json')
      .map(res => res.json());
  }
}
```

I know the error, that is with this code .map(res => res.json());

Here is the error log

> Typescript Error Property 'json' does not exist on type 'Object'.
>
> ```
> src/providers/weather/weather.ts
>   return this.http.get(this.url+'/'+state+'/'+city+'.json')
>     .map(res => res.json());
> }
> ```
>
> Ionic Framework: 3.9.2 Ionic App Scripts: 3.1.9 Angular Core: 5.2.10
>   Angular Compiler CLI: 5.2.10 Node: 9.2.1 OS Platform: Linux 4.13
>   Navigator Platform: Linux x86_64 User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux
>   x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132
>   Safari/537.36

Give me a solution please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to call **`.json()`** with **[`httpClient`](https://angular.io/guide/http)** because the response is JSON by default

```
return this.http.get(this.url+'/'+state+'/'+city+'.json')
    .map(res => res);
```

Comment: Thank you my problem is solved for now. Lets move ahead hope it dont create more problem for this.